# Folder Structure and Xcode Workspace for a Cocoapod

Tags: cocoapods, tttattritubedlabel

I would like to distribute some classes as a Cocoapod. I intend to provide the following:

- The classes themselves (a few UIView subclasses)
- A small example application

I have been looking through some well established Github projects and it looks like there is no single established way to set up my project. Should I use a single workspace with multiple projects? One project and one simple folder (for the views)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

One (perhaps obvious) requirement - once the structure is in place and the pod is downloaded, the example application should not be included.

Perhaps there are some tutorials out there? I've spent a few hours looking around and making some attempts but I'm invariably hitting some obstacle or another.

For example: If I have one project and one folder in the workspace (which I copied from [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel)) I can't get the library classes into the compile sources without them duplicating themselves into the demo project.

Each attempt seemed to hit a similar snafu so I'm hoping there's a 'right' way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following demo the simplest to reproduce: http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/07/21/how-to-open-source-objective-c-code/